# MySql - Why does ENUM take more space than expected?

Tags: mysql, enums

I did a test to make sure I know how ENUM works and how it handles storage space... and got different results than expected.

One table with one field of type `VARCHAR(100)` populated with 1,000,000 rows. Each row has a value randomly selected from 1 of 6 strings, length of 100.

Then, conversion to `ENUM`, then back to `VARCHAR(100)`. Here are the results (Data size).

**1. Rows 1,000,000 = 99.2 MiB, VARCHAR(100)**

**2. Rows 1,000,000 = 6,835.9 KiB, Enum 
('blah100Characters1','blah100Characters2',...,'blah100Characters6')**

**3. Rows 1,000,000 99.2 MiB, VARCHAR(100)**

The `VARCHAR(100)` type reported as expected and matches the MySQL specification in the manual of ("L + 1 bytes, 0 <= L <= 255")
1,000,000 x 100 = 100,000,000 = 99.2 MiB

---Edit: Well, plus that one extra byte, but that's irrelevant to this discussion :o)

however, according to the MySQL specification of ENUM ("1 or 2 bytes, depending on the number of enumeration values (65,535 values maximum)"), with 6 possible combinations I'd expect there to be a data requirement of 1 byte per row.
1,000,000 x 1 = 1,000,000 = 976.5 KiB

Can anyone explain to me why the converted table requires 6,835.9 KiB, which is, oddly enough, almost exactly 7 times more than expected?

Comment: Looks like some data padding is being applied, though the amount is not 2-power round ;-)

Comment: Which storage engine are you using? How are you calculating the size?

Comment: Storage engine is MyISAM, and I'm going by what is reported in the "Space Usage" table at the bottom of the "Structure" area for that table in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Could you show the output of `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'tablename' \G`?

Comment: I'm a little output-hobbled, but I can say it states: Engine=MyISAM, Version=10, rows=1000000, AvgRowLength=7, DataLength=7000000, MaxDataLength=1970324836974591, Indexlength=1024

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It adds up to 7 bytes (I get the same results); some of the space is padding and some is for a delete flag.

To prove that there is padding, add additional enums (or tiny integers). The size of the table does not change.

To prove that there is a delete flag, delete a row in the middle. The size of the table does not change.

According to [this page](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/04/23/efficient-boolean-value-storage-for-innodb-tables/), it has to do with `myisam_data_pointer_size` having a default value of 6 bytes (plus 1 byte for delete).

And he seems to be correct, as if I do this:

```
alter table foo MAX_ROWS=10;
```

the size of the table decreases.

Furthermore, from [this "bug" report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=42481), it sounds like a deleted record is stored as a pointer to the next record. If so, that would mean the minimum space for any row would be the pointer size (6 bytes, by default) plus a delete byte. This is because if a record is deleted, the delete byte is set, and then the other 6 bytes are used to point to the next record.

If you want more info, I'd read up on the "delete link chain" of MyISAM tables (when using fixed record counts).

Comment: Hey, I think you've got it. I found this [link in the mysql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_myisam_data_pointer_size) and the default is 6 bytes which, plus 1 for my actual reference byte for the data is 7.

Comment: @Rickaroo, I'm pretty sure the additional byte is for the delete flag. Each record has a hidden delete flag. Your enum's byte is part of those 6 bytes reserved for a possible row pointer. (If the delete flag is 0, then it knows the 6 bytes belong to your data.) I believe this only applies to records with fixed lengths. i.e., Your varchar version isn't fixed length, so it doesn't get same sort of delete+pointer treatment.

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand. And when I haven't specified that my table will be a shorter maximum length, it just allocates the 6 bytes knowing that the table could grow massive and require them for row indexing? One thing I've learned is that, while I was assuming the VARCHAR wasn't adding on values, in fact a VARCHAR(100) single field gives a row length of 104. So my error was in assuming that there was no padding with the VARCHAR. Thanks!